# svn:externals write dependant project at same level as main project not under it

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I'm trying to find a way of including a dependant project with another project when checking out from svn using netbeans.

We have a project that uses the jar from another of our projects and locally would be included with a relative url of ../ReqProj/dist/ReqProj.jar

each of our projects has its own repository on the same server and I'd like to be able to set svn externals to give a structure like ..

> NetbeansProjects
>   ^
>   MainProject     -     ReqProj

.. when its checked out, but setting the property to ..

> ReqProj svn/reqprojrepo/ReqProj

.. creates a structure like..

> NetbeansProjects
>  ^
>  MainProject
>  ^
>  ReqProj

If I try something like

> ../ReqProj svn/reqprojrepo/ReqProj

The property is rejected for containing ../.

Is there anyway of accomplishing what I'm trying to acheive or should I just include the built required jar in the main project?

Comment: Add the exact svn location/link in the svn:externals. That is how I'm using it.

Comment: I've tried using 'ReqProj https:/urltoserver/svn/reponam/ReqProj' but it opens it under the main project not alongside it.